# Duplicate data added to REALM once view loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode7, realm

I had a little problem which is everytime I come back to main view controller from details view controller I got duplicate data added to REALM database. I also tried to replace the networking code in viewDidLoad but I got this error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 2 is out of bounds*.**  Below is my code :

```
#import "HomeTVC.h"
#import "facebook.h"
#import "HomeTVCell.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "PageVideosCVC.h"
#import "HomePageList.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

@interface HomeTVC ()<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *userPageLikesParams;
    NSMutableArray *pagesInfo;
    NSArray *pagesInfoFromRealm;
    facebook *fb;
    HomePageList *homePageList;

}
@end

@implementation HomeTVC

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    // Add HUD
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    userPageLikesParams = @{@"fields": @"about,name,created_time,picture",@"limit": @"10"} ;

    fb = [[facebook alloc] init];

    [fb getUserPagelikes:userPageLikesParams completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *pagesResult) {

        if (pagesResult != nil) {

            [pagesInfo addObjectsFromArray:[pagesResult valueForKeyPath:@"data"]];

            //           pagesInfo = pagesResult[@"data"];

            // Delete all available data in REALM

            RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            [realm deleteAllObjects];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];

            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            for(NSDictionary *pageInfoToSaveInRealm in pagesInfo){
                HomePageList *homePages = [[HomePageList alloc] init];
                homePages.pageID = pageInfoToSaveInRealm[@"id"];
                homePages.pageName = pageInfoToSaveInRealm[@"name"];
                homePages.pageProfilePic = [pageInfoToSaveInRealm valueForKeyPath:@"picture.data.url"];
                [realm addObject:homePages];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    RLMRealm *realmMainThread = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
                    RLMResults *pagesInformation = [HomePageList allObjectsInRealm:realmMainThread];
                    pagesInfoFromRealm = pagesInformation;
                    NSLog(@"ayam : %d", (int)pagesInfoFromRealm.count);

                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                });

            }
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];

        }

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            pagesInfoFromRealm = [HomePageList allObjects];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    pagesInfo = [NSMutableArray array];

    // [facebook currentFBAccessToken];
    // [facebook getFBUserInfo];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (pagesInfoFromRealm == nil) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"table count : %d", (int)pagesInfoFromRealm.count);
        return pagesInfoFromRealm.count;
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    HomeTVCell *cell = (HomeTVCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //  NSLog(@"pagesInfoFromRealm : %@", pagesInfoFromRealm);

    homePageList = pagesInfoFromRealm[[indexPath item]];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:homePageList.pageProfilePic];

    // cache the image using sdwebimage
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    cell.pageProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius= 30.0;
    [cell.pageProfilePic sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
    cell.pageName.text = homePageList.pageName;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PageVideosCVC *pageVideo = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"videoDetails"];
    homePageList = pagesInfoFromRealm[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"pagesInfoFromRealm array count: %d", (int)pagesInfoFromRealm.count);

    NSLog(@"homepagelist data: %@", pagesInfoFromRealm[indexPath.row]);
    pageVideo.pageID = homePageList[@"pageID"];
    pageVideo.pageName = homePageList[@"pageName"];
    [self presentViewController:pageVideo animated:YES completion:nil];

}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: move all your realm code to custom method eg.`(void)doAfterGetData` or something and call it only when u need it...so u can control it better than put it in `viewdidappear`

Answer (score 2):

You are adding data in your `viewDidAppear:`. That method is called every time the view shows up. So it would also be called when the user comes back from detail view to this view.

Instead, move this to `viewDidLoad` or move the code to another method and call it only when needed.

If you really need to have that code in your `viewDidAppear`, and assuming you have marked the `pageId` as a primary key for `HomePageList`, you can do an `addOrUpdateObject:` instead of `addObject:`. This will ensure that if the object already exists in Realm, it is only updated not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that this is executed only once, you can move the actions into an `isMovingToParent` check, which is a special `BOOL` method that can only be used during `UIViewController` transitions:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ( [self isMovingToParentViewController]) {

        // Action
    }
}
```